# Percentage of day that has elapsed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We're measuring actual values against a target. We have a overall target for a day (a 24 hour period) but we need to calculate a target for any given time to measure our progress 'so far'.

Obviously we need to proportion the overall target to the given time; so if it's midday, then the progressive target is half the daily target, and at 6am the progressive target would be a quarter of the daily target - and so on.

What's the most efficient way to do this in SQL? There is an obvious solution but it's not very pretty - I'd ideally like to be able to convert a `DATETIME` into a total number of milliseconds in a single operation.

Comment: With due respect, not very clear what you're asking. Can you please expand? This "target" - is it the sysdate, at the time of execution of a particular SP or query? Is it stored somewhere in the database? And the amount it's compared to - is it in a field, a parameter, something else? An example of what you have and what you'd like to accomplish would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the percentage of a day that's complete, you can do this:

```
select datediff(MILLISECOND, CONVERT(date, getdate()), GETDATE())/864000.0
```

Do you really need to the millisecond?

Comment: Fantastic! No, I don't need millisecond in this case, and minute would be enough - I'm just looking for the most reusable pattern.